# General Integer properties

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

How many two-digit positive integers $N$ have the property that the sum of $N$ and the number obtained by reversing the order of the digits of $N$ is a perfect square? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Suppose the number were $10a+b$ (*where $a$ and $b$ are both integers in $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$*).  Then we are interested in determining which $a$ and $b$ make it so that $(10a+b)+(10b+a)$ is a square.  What do you notice about the factors of the above after simplifying?

Comment: I got the second method but can you tell me how I can go about writing this program if it's not too much trouble. Thanks btw.

Comment: @Prakhar go to stackoverflow for programming questions, not here, but the pseudocode will be simply:  iterate over all pairs of $(a,b)$... ask if $(10a+b)+(10b+a)$ is a square.  If yes, add one to the count........ it really is as short and simple of a loop as they come for programming, easily first semester material for any programming class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the two numbers  whose sum you want

That is $10a+b$ and $10b+a$

Their sum is $11(a+b)$

Since $11$ is a prime ,, so $(a+b)$ must equal to $11$ for being a perfect square

So the numbers  whose sum of digits is $11$ will satisfy your condition

Numbers are $29,92, 38,83,47,74,56,65$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Always love to help!! -:)

Comment: Well.. I remember a similar question was asked in RMO, right?? +1

Comment: Yeah I too @Vidyanshu

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program and it gave me this:

$0 + 0 = 0$ (if you consider $00$ as a two digit number)

$92 + 29 = 121$

$83 + 38 = 121$

$74 + 47 = 121$

$65 + 56= 121$

Comment: It didn't specify that the number must be larger than its reverse, you are missing half of the results.

Comment: @JMoravitz I deleted the reverse because thats obvious. But yeah, there are 8 of them (or 9 if you count $00$).